# How do I create bar-charts in SVG from my XML using XQuery and/or XSLT in eXist-db

Tags: xpath, svg, xquery, exist-db

I can't find any existing solutions because I do not think that anybody else has used eXist-db to do this yet. Does anybody know how to draw bar charts using SVG from eXist-db?

Firstly date:

DTD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!ELEMENT akweny (akwen+)>
<!ELEMENT akwen (nazwa, typ, powierzchnia, akweny?)>
<!ELEMENT nazwa (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT typ (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT powierzchnia (#PCDATA)>
```

And XML for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE akweny SYSTEM "akweny.dtd">
    <akweny>
        <akwen>
            <nazwa>Atlantycki</nazwa>
            <typ>ocean</typ>
            <powierzchnia>106450</powierzchnia>
            <akweny>
                <akwen>
                    <nazwa>Północne</nazwa>
                    <typ>morze</typ>
                    <powierzchnia>750</powierzchnia>
                </akwen>
                <akwen>
                    <nazwa>Batyckie</nazwa>
                    <typ>morze</typ>
                    <powierzchnia>386</powierzchnia>
                    <akweny>
                        <akwen>
                            <nazwa>Botnicka</nazwa>
                            <typ>zatoka</typ>
                            <powierzchnia>117</powierzchnia>
                        </akwen>
                    </akweny>
                </akwen>
            </akweny>
        </akwen>
        <akwen>
            <nazwa>Spokojny</nazwa>
            <typ>ocean</typ>
            <powierzchnia>179700</powierzchnia>
        </akwen>
    </akweny>
```

I know eXist-db has some XSLT transformation functions, e.g.

```
transform:stream-transform($node-tree as node()*, $stylesheet as item(), 
$parameters as node()?) as item()
```

But how the hell can I use this? I can't find any examples. I don know how to use it...

Here is my link:

```
bars.xq?nazwa=anyNazwa&typ=anyTyp&powierzchnia=100
```

It should show Any of `nazwa`, any of `typ` and greater than `powierzchnia` of `100`.

Here is my simple XQuery

```
let $nodes := doc('/db/Dane/akweny.xml')//akweny[ancestor::akwen/nazwa=request:get-parameter("nazwa", ()) and typ=request:get-parameter("typ", ())]
        for $x in $nodes/* 
        let $nazwa := $x/nazwa/text()
        let $typ := $x/typ/text()
        let $powierzchnia := $x/powierzchnia/text()
            where $powierzchnia >= number(request:get-parameter("powierchnia", ()))
```

My question is:

How to show all the children of the selected node by: `nazwa`, `typ` and `powierchnia` in the form of a bar chart?

Comment: If you want to show the xml data as bar charts, you should give the d3 javascript library a try.

Comment: Your question is not directly related to eXist-db, what you are really asking is how do I create bar-charts in SVG from my XML using XQuery and/or XSLT.

Well you could do this easily in either XQuery or XSLT. There is nothing particularly eXist specific about this, unless you want to run your XSLT from XQuery, then you can use eXist's transform functions.

Comment: I can't javascript...
Title is corect now.
How i can use Exist transfom function? I can't faind any examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of doing this in pure XQuery, this will work in eXist, or any other XQuery 1.0 processor:

```
declare variable $local:max-graph-height := 400; (: pixels :)
declare variable $local:graph-bar-width := 120; (: pixels :)
declare variable $local:graph-bar-spacing := 10; (: pixels :)
declare variable $local:graph-text-below := 20; (: pixels :)

let $awkeny := doc("/db/Dane/akweny.xml")//akwen[xs:int(powierzchnia) gt 100]
let $max-powierzchnia := max($awkeny/powierzchnia)

return

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
        id="graph"
        height="{ $local:max-graph-height + ($local:graph-text-below * 2) }" 
        width="{ ($local:graph-bar-width + $local:graph-bar-spacing) * count($awkeny) }">

        <linearGradient x1="0%" x2="0%" y1="10%" y2="100%" id="gradient">
            <stop style="stop-color:#0000FF" offset="0"></stop>
            <stop style="stop-color:#FFFFFF" offset="1"></stop>
        </linearGradient>

        {
        for $awken at $i in $awkeny
        let $height := (xs:float($awken/*:powierzchnia) div $max-powierzchnia) * $local:max-graph-height
        let $x := ($i - 1) * ($local:graph-bar-with + $local:graph-bar-spacing)
        let $y := $local:max-graph-height - $height
        return
            (
            <rect width="{$local:graph-bar-with}" 
                height="{$height}" x="{$x}" y="{$y}" 
                fill="url(#gradient)"></rect>,
            <text x="{$x}" 
                y="{$local:max-graph-height + $local:graph-text-below}" 
                fill="red">{$awken/*:nazwa/text()}</text>
            )
        }
    </svg>
```

The above XQuery when run on your awkeny.xml produces a bar-chart in SVG that looks like the following: [image: SVG Bar Chart of awkeny.xml generated from XQuery]

Now I think you just need to work that into your XQuery in eXist as you appear from your example to be taking parameters from the incoming HTTP Request, however I can see from your question that you already know how to do that. So you should now be well on your way...

Comment: God save as u @adamretter!

Comment: how to show typ not name in bars?

i know there is:

`<text x="{$x}" y="{$local:max-graph-height + $local:graph-text-below}" fill="red">{$awken/*:nazwa/text()}</text>`
But this only chage displa nazwa to other. But how to change this bars to show how many `typ` is there?

Comment: @Brieg I am not sure how you mean when you say 'how to show typ' not name in the bars? Do you want the bars to be labelled 'morze', 'morze', 'zatoka' and 'ocean' instead of the value from `nazwa`?

Comment: `morze`, `zatoka` and `ocean` or other depend `typ`. There can't be duplicate of typ. Bars shold show how many `morze`,`zatoka` and/or `ocean` is greater than or equal input `powierzchnia`. For example `powierchnia >= 200` there should 2 bars whit (50%)2 ocean and (50%)2 morze

Comment: THX! U all! U save my ass ;)

Answer (score 1):

you could have look at the eXist-db jfreechart extension:

https://github.com/eXist-db/jfreechart

When the image type `svgz` is specified, a compressed SVG file is generated. Precompiled XAR files (including a simple demo) is available both on GitHub and via the eXist-db package manager (public repo)